# Is their any public udid to add in provisioning profile to make ipa run on any device via itunes application

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, udid

One of my client send me a ipa which i can install in my ipad or other ipad weather the client doesn't have my device UDID.

Is their any public udid attched in his provisioning profile to make able to install on any device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That build may be signed with enterprise distribution profile. 
Its illegal according to apple that distributing enterprise application out of the organization.

Comment: Yeah !! They must be using  enterprise developer program, $300

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it with iOS Development Certificates.**

It's illegal, If they are using enterprise distribution profile for doing this.

The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is intended for companies who create proprietary, in-house iOS apps for internal deployment within the company only. A valid Dun & Bradstreet (D-U-N-S) number is required for program enrollment.

The Apple ID associated with an iOS Enterprise Program cannot be used for a standard iOS or Mac Developer Program.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the provisioning profile of the ipa with one that includes your device and re-sign it like so

```
unzip your.ipa
cd Payload
cp new-ad-hoc-that-includes-your-device.mobileprovision your.app/embedded.mobileprovision
codesign -f -s YourDistributionSigningIdentity --resource-rules your.app/ResourceRules.plist your.app 
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v -o `pwd`/new.ipa your.app
```

`new.ipa` should install on your device.